# Why does bigquery go client library give; Error: bigquery: schema inference for recursive type *bigquery.FieldSchema

Tags: google-bigquery

The following code using the go client library for BigQuery returns an error

```
type GceQuotaRow struct {
  CustomerProjectNumber  int64
  ExecutionProjectNumber int64
  Region                 string
  Metric                 string
  Limit                  float64
}

ds := b.bq.Dataset(task.Options.Dataset)
table := ds.Table(task.Options.Table)

u := table.Uploader()

rows := []bigquery.StructSaver{}
// rows := []*GceQuotaRow{}

schema, err := bigquery.InferSchema(GceQuotaRow{})
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf("Inferring BigQuery scheme failed; %v", util.Pformat(err))
    return backfill.TaskPermanentError
}

// Construct an insertID to dedupe insertions on a best effort basis.

for _, region := range res.GetRegionalQuotas() {
    for _, q := range region.GetQuotas() {

        r := &GceQuotaRow{
            CustomerProjectNumber:  task.CustomerProjectNumber,
            ExecutionProjectNumber: res.GetExecutionProjectNumber(),
            Region:                 region.GetRegion(),
            Metric:                 q.GetMetric(),
            Limit:                  q.GetLimit(),
        }
        h := sha256.New()
        h.Write([]byte(util.Pformat(r)))

        // Use the sha256 of the row as the InsertId to avoid duplicates.
        insertId := fmt.Sprintf("%x", h.Sum(nil))

        rows = append(rows, bigquery.StructSaver{
            Schema:   schema,
            InsertID: insertId,
            Struct:   r,
        })
        // rows = append(rows, r)
    }
}

err = u.Put(ctx, rows)
if err != nil {
    putErr, isErr := err.(bigquery.PutMultiError)
    if isErr {
        for _, e := range putErr {
            log.Errorf("There was a problem writing Row for customer project: %v, Error: %v", task.CustomerProjectNumber, util.Pformat(e))
        }
    } else {
        log.Errorf("There was a problem writing GCE Quota Rows for customer project: %v, Error: %v", task.CustomerProjectNumber, err)
    }
}
```

The call to Put returns the error:

```
Error: bigquery: schema inference for recursive type *bigquery.FieldSchema
```

I don't understand why the Put would return an error about inferring the schema because the InferSchema call succeeded so the schema should be passed to the structsaver.

I want to use StructSaver so I can provide an insert id to dedupe rows.

Comment: Facing similar issues too, but I have embedded field in my struct which seems to be raising the error.

Comment: Any updates on the problem? Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this and puzzled it out. The reason this happens is that the concrete `bigquery.StructSaver` does not implement the `bigquery.ValueSaver` interface, since its method operates on the pointer type `*bigquery.StructSaver`. This causes the golang client library to fall back to its generic schema inference logic on your struct (in this case `bigquery.StructSaver`), which then fails as `bigquery.StructSaver` nests other structs and thus would not itself be a valid object for saving in BigQuery. You can fix your code as follows:

```
for _, region := range res.GetRegionalQuotas() {
    for _, q := range region.GetQuotas() {

        r := &GceQuotaRow{
            CustomerProjectNumber:  task.CustomerProjectNumber,
            ExecutionProjectNumber: res.GetExecutionProjectNumber(),
            Region:                 region.GetRegion(),
            Metric:                 q.GetMetric(),
            Limit:                  q.GetLimit(),
        }
        h := sha256.New()
        h.Write([]byte(util.Pformat(r)))

        // Use the sha256 of the row as the InsertId to avoid duplicates.
        insertId := fmt.Sprintf("%x", h.Sum(nil))

        rows = append(rows, &bigquery.StructSaver{
            Schema:   schema,
            InsertID: insertId,
            Struct:   r,
        })
        // rows = append(rows, r)
    }
}

err = u.Put(ctx, rows)
if err != nil {
    putErr, isErr := err.(bigquery.PutMultiError)
    if isErr {
        for _, e := range putErr {
            log.Errorf("There was a problem writing Row for customer project: %v, Error: %v", task.CustomerProjectNumber, util.Pformat(e))
        }
    } else {
        log.Errorf("There was a problem writing GCE Quota Rows for customer project: %v, Error: %v", task.CustomerProjectNumber, err)
    }
}
```

I hope this helps (perhaps if not you, two years after the fact, then anyone else who stumbles upon this)!